# Why is this limit infinity and not 1?

Tags: limits

> $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{1}{t} - \dfrac{1}{t^2+t}$

For $t \neq 0$, you can rewrite this as $\dfrac{1}{t+1}$. Obviously the limit of that function as $t \to 0$ is 1. So why is the above limit $\infty$? You merely approach $t=0$, you never attain it, yet for some reason you still can't do what I did. Why? I thought the whole point of limits was approaching something without ever reaching it.

Comment: Why do you think it should be $\infty$?

Comment: The limit is $1$ indeed.

Comment: Functions can reach the point referenced in a limit, or not. In particular, changing the value of a function just at a given point where a limit is taken does not change what the limit is. Anyway, $\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^2+t} = \frac{t^2+t - t}{t^3+t^2}=\frac{t^2}{t^3+t^2}=\frac{1}{1+t}$ if $t \neq 0$, so indeed the limit is $1$.

Comment: @Arthur I thought I wolframalpha'd it and it gave me $\infty$.. might have imagined that.

Comment: You might've WA'd the expression `1/t - 1/t^2 + t`, which certainly doesn't converge, or it might be something else. If you do put in parentheses in the above expression, though, WA will almost surely return $1$, which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is indeed $1$, and this is a good example of why we have to be careful when thinking about limits.

Intuitively, the limit you're asking about might look like ${1\over t}-{1\over t^2}$. Especially if you've been working with limits at infinity, this looks like a reasonable simplification to make. However, $t$ is going to $0$! So $t$ is not negligible compared to $t^2$; in fact, it dwarfs it. The limit of ${1\over t}-{1\over t^2}$ as $t$ approaches $0$ is indeed (negative) infinity; however, this is because the denominator "$t^2$" is so much smaller than the denominator "$t$". By contrast, "$t$ and "$t^2+t$" are roughly the same size when $t$ is close to zero, so we shouldn't expect the limit to go to either infinity.

---

EDIT: note that the function ${1\over t}-{1\over t^2}+t$ - which you may have WA'd accidentally - behaves the same as ${1\over t}-{1\over t^2}$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.